# By what mechanism are lasers meant to destroy an entire planet?

Tags: star-trek, star-wars, star-trek-voyager, planets

## Question turned out to be off-topic. ["Migrated" to Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/100423/36).

---

I'm referring to two events that I recall immediately (the destruction of the Borg planet in the [Scorpion](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Scorpion_(episode)) episode of *Star Trek: Voyager*; and the destruction of *Alderaan* in *Star Wars*), but there are dozens of similar examples, if not hundreds, in the entire SF&F canon.

What events are actually meant to happen when a high-energy laser beam hits a planet’s surface that lead to the destruction of the entire planet?

Some of my (maybe very lunatic) possibilities and theories (to verify):

1. The laser beam penetrates the surface, reaches the core, raises its temperature to boiling or even melting point, and pressure in the surrounding area causes the entire planet to explode.
2. The laser beam hits only the surface or not-so-deep areas beneath it, but due to surface’s stability being destroyed, this is enough to cause the explosion of entire planet.
3. The laser beam doesn't even hit the surfaces, but causes changes to the atmosphere starting some kind of destructive process.

Is there any, verifiable by our present knowledge (geology, physics, chemistry), *common means of explanation* that can be adapted to each or most of examples of such events? Or must each of these examples and situations be treated separately (and each book, story or scenario author does it by its own -- i.e. brings its own theory or explanation)?

**EDIT, to clarify**: *I really believe, this is a pure science-fiction question. I'm referring to exactly these two examples I given (destruction of Borg planet in Star Trek and destruction of Alderaan in Star Wars). And this question is tagged with proper tags. This question somehow turned into be too wide or even general, but the key facts remains. Few days ago I watched VOY: Scorpion again and become really interested, how a fairly small armada of nine (?) bio-ships, can destroy entire planet with a just single blast of laser beam? Star Wars example is an addition, but in the very same mood -- in my humble opinion, even that big Death Star shouldn't have (by a very wide and general means) a firepower enough to blast entire planet hell (since Death Star itself is smaller than an average moon, if I'm not mistaken, and for sure much smaller than Alderaan).*

Comment: *"high-energy laser beam"*  It would seem that a lot of the plausibility of a laser destroying a planet would depend on the exact (or at least order of magnitude) figure of **high-energy** is pinned down, and released in what amount of time..  Of the 3 scenarios outlined, I find the first most plausible.  The 2nd might result in a shock wave that knocks a large chunk off the opposite side of the planet, but not a 'complete annihilation' as generally depicted.  And the 3rd might blow the atmosphere away and melt, boil or ionize the first ground it reached.

Comment: Maybe using "high-energy" word was wrong in this case, but let me underline, that with this question, I'm actually looking for a description of a process, that causes entire planet do be destroyed (explode), without going too deep into details, how much energy or what kind of chemical reaction goes here! :] I understand, that such details are beyond any _common_ answers (for all or most of the cases), that anyone can formulate.

Comment: @Richard Can you be more specific? Two questions? What kind of?

Comment: @tredjer - ignore my previous comment. On re-reading the question I've realised that it's actually a real-world science question and hence unsuitable for SF&S:SE

Comment: @Richard Please, take a look at my edit to this question -- I really do believe, this is pure science-fiction question and don't want to ask it on any real-science SE site.

Comment: Could be a question for https://what-if.xkcd.com/ :)

Comment: @JohannBlais: more or less already done towards the end of http://what-if.xkcd.com/20/ - OK, it doesn't involve a laster, but I suspect that at that energy level, it makes little difference.

Comment: @trejder: “real-world science hasn't ever seen an entire planet destroyed as an effect of hitting it with a laser, right?” — I like to think I’d remember that :)

Comment: @trejder: Regarding whether this is a sci-fi question, this site is for questions *about* science fiction (i.e existing works of fiction). If you’re asking what explanations authors have given for how planets explode from laser fire, I think it’s fine (although it’s a bit of a list question). If you’re asking for how this *could* happen in the real world, that’s a question about real-world science, albeit a speculative one. It’s a fine line, admittedly.

Comment: @all Very sorry for confusing you all. Please, take a look once again at edited and clarified part in the end of my question -- I'm referring to exactly these two examples I given. For this, I'm again voting to not close this question and again, I'm pretty sure, this is full-featured science-fiction question.

Comment: Thought it might not answer this question, see also Sam's Geocide pages which tell a lot about how to destroy a planet: http://qntm.org/geocide

Comment: Seems more like a "physics of sci-fi" question than a sci-fi question, but basically you just have to supply the particles of the planet with enough kinetic energy in the form of heat so most or all of the particles achieve escape velocity, which is equivalent to overcoming the gravitational binding energy--there's an analysis of the energy needed at http://www.stardestroyer.net/Empire/Tech/Beam/DeathStar.html

Comment: b_jonas In my opinion, your comment is actually a full-featured answer, because it points out to the source of information, that can directly answer my question. There's only one "reopen" vote left, required to reopen this question. If this happens, I would strongly advice you to reformulate your comment to full answer, so I can pick it and bring you some rep.

Comment: @Hypnosifl See my comment to _b_jonas_ above, as your case is the same. I think, that your comment could be an answer, because it points to a very interesting source of information. If this question gets reopen, I would strongly advice you to reformulate your comment to full answer, so I can pick it and bring you some rep.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt: Your What-If link was an incredibly fun read! But is the high energy required to cause such kind of planetary destruction feasible to be realized via lasers? It is one thing to have a fast-moving rock, but it is another to have just photons. And don't forget the part about exploding, which even a fast rock can't cause?

Comment: @user21820: a fast rock most definitely can and does cause explosions of enormous power. The Chelyabinsk meteor is estimated to have been travelling at 19 km/s and caused an explosion over 30 times as powerful as the Hiroshima bomb merely by hitting our atmosphere. And yes, potons can most certainly do that too, it's really only about how much energy you can deliver. And I'm not aware of a theoretical limit of energy a laser could have. The practical question of how to build and power a laser capable of such extreme output is of course a different matter.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt: That is nowhere near the notion of a planetary-sized explosion of the sort in science fiction, where the entire planet breaks apart into chunks that fly off in different directions. The meteors in our earth's past did not at all cause the planet to break up.

Comment: @user21820: that's because we would not be here to ponder these question of such an event had occurred. And the reason it cannot realistically occur like in the what-if is that there most likely no event in the universe that would lead to solid objects bigger than individual nucleons travelling at such speeds. But do note that the Theia impact hypothesis suggests the moon was formed by an impact that *almost* broke apart earth - the impacting object was just very large and not as ridiculously fast.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt: As far as I can see, the conclusion is still that there is no apparent physical mechanism for the literal blowing up of a planet by laser. It is like the difference between throwing a rock at an egg to break it and putting the egg in a microwave to explode it. No?

Comment: @user21820: well, if you expect "blowing up" to end with solid chunks that keep their form and float apart slowly, then that is simply not how physics works at planetary sizes, since planets are kept together by gravity, not the strength of their material. Then again, to use your analogy, if you shoot a bullet at an egg, the result would look rather more like it exploding from a laser than having a rock thrown at it - but a bullet is really just a fast rock.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt: Sorry. Analogies always backfire. I did not mean to imply any relation with strength of material, but that the earth's crust is like a thin shell. Anyway, I thought you should get my point, since there would not be chunks (solid or not) that fly apart with significant velocities. Of course they can't just float apart slowly since they are still bound by the same gravity. And that is my point; to have much energy to make them suddenly fly apart in a manner that could be called an explosion, the energy must be stored and then released in a burst.

Comment: @user21820: And a laser of sufficient power stores its energy as photons, and releases it in a burst when all those photons hit a target. If it's powerful enough, there is no difference whatsoever between that scenario and any other that delivers a lot of energy very suddenly.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt: You don't get my point, so never mind.